# Create a 2D list with variable length [torch]

Tags: arrays, lua, torch

I want to create a 2D list that can have elements of variable lengths inside, for example, if I have a 10x10 list in MATLAB, I can
define it with:

```
z = cell(10,10)
```

and start assigning some elements by doing this:

```
z{2}{3} = ones(3,1)
z{1}{1} = zeros(100,1)
z{1}{2} = []
z{1}{3} = randn(20,1)
...
```

What is the optimal way to define such empty 2D list in torch? Moreover, is there a way to exploit the tensor structure to do this?

In python, I can do something along this to define an empty 10x10 2D list:

```
z = [[None for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]
```

My best guess for torch is doing something like

```
z = torch.Tensor(10,10)

for i=1,10 do
  for j=1,10 do
    z[{{i},{j}}] = torch.Tensor()
  end
end
```

but, this does not work, and defining a tensor inside a tensor seems like a bad idea ...

This is a follow up to the question asked here (however in the link it is asked in python): [Create 2D lists in python with variable length indexed vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192915/create-2d-lists-in-python-with-variable-length-indexed-vectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Torch's Google Group forums. Agreeing that tables is the solution:

```
z = {}

for i=1,10 do

  z[i] = {}
  for j=1,10 do
    z[i][j] = torch.Tensor()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation I've read, tensors only support primitive numeric data types. You won't be able to use tensor for your intended usage. Leverage tables.

```
local function makeMatrix(initialVal, ...)
    local isfunc = type(initialVal) == "function"
    local dimtable = {...}
    local function helper(depth)
        if depth == 0 then
            return isfunc and initialVal() or initialVal
        else
            local plane = {}
            for i = 1, dimtable[depth] do
                plane[i] = helper(depth-1)
            end
            return plane
        end
    end
    return helper(#dimtable)
end

p = makeMatrix(0, 2, 3, 5) -- makes 3D matrix of size 2x3x5 with all elements initialized to 0

makeMatrix(torch.Tensor, m ,n)
```